# How to request a permission of type System.Net.WebPermission in SQL Server CLR?

Tags: sql-server, webapi, webrequest

I have created a sqlproj for SQL Server CLR to allows SQL Server call web API, the code like this:

```cs
public partial class SqlServerClrClient
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString Query(string url, string jobName, string sql)
    {
        var jobNameBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jobName));
        var sqlBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sql));
        var param =
            $"{{\"Id\":\"{Guid.NewGuid()}\",\"JobNameBase64\":\"{jobNameBase64}\",\"SqlBase64\":\"{sqlBase64}\",\"CreatedUtcTime\":\"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}\"}}";
        var postData = "cmdParam=" + param;
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        var httpRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (var stream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        using (var httpResponse = httpRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            var responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            if (responseStream is null)
                return SqlString.Null;
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

And I have turn on the TRUSTWORTHY like this

```sql
ALTER DATABASE TESTDB SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
```

But when I call it the SQL Server throws an error

```bash
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "GatewayQuery": 
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
System.Security.SecurityException: 
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet)
   at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand()
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckConnectPermission(Uri uri, Boolean needExecutionContext)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor(Uri uri, ServicePoint servicePoint)
   at System.Net.HttpRequestCreator.Create(Uri Uri)
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase)
   at System.Net.WebRequest.CreateHttp(Uri requestUri)
   at CIPGatewaySqlServerClrClient.Query(String url, String jobName, String sql)
```

How can I solve this problem?

The TRUSTWORTHY has been turn on.

Comment: What permission setting did you use when you created the CLR assembly?

Comment: Hi @Larnu, the permission has been set to unsafe.